# NVDA screen reader freezes or not responding when android studio connected to usb debug mode

Tags: android, accessibility, screen, reader, nvda

I am visually impaired and using screen reader. When I use NVDA to access android studio, it works fine, but when I am connected to USB debug mode, NVDA will freeze or not respond. Anyone know why and what the solution is for that? perhaps, alternative tool for developing native android app. thank you.

Android Studio Version 3.6.0.AI-192.7142.36.36.6241897
NVDA version: 2019.3